# Django + PostgreSQL: Synchronize database with external source

Tags: sql, database, django, postgresql, data-synchronization

I'm looking for a way to synchronize some tables in database with an external source. I would check this external source every couple of hours for changes and if there are any, I would update my database.

My question is, if anybody knows about an existing app, that accepts some kind of data structure (a python dict) and translates this into database entries?

Here is an example: Lets say I have the following models:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharFieldmax_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Unit(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class UnitTranslations(models.Model):
    unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

So I could have corresponding data, that looks like this:

```
data = [
    {
        "label": "AB",
        "name": "some random name",
        "translations": [
            {
                "name": "some random name in german",
                "language": {
                    "tag": "de",
                    "name": "german"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "some random name in spanish",
                "language": {
                    "tag": "es",
                    "name": "spanish"
                }
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "OR",
        "name": "some other random name",
        "translations": [
            {
                "name": "some other random name in german",
                "language": {
                    "tag": "de",
                    "name": "german"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "some other random name in spanish",
                "language": {
                    "tag": "es",
                    "name": "spanish"
                }
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

So, I would like to take this structure (plus some meta informations on what the actuals models are, what attributes can be seen as IDs and so on), and have my program automatically update the necessary tables.

To finish my example, those are in short the main steps that need to be performed:

- Is already a Unit with label "AB"? (otherwise create it)
- Does it have the name "some random name"? (otherwise change it)
- Do we have the languages german and spanish? (otherwise create them)
- Do we have translations for german and spanish? (otherwise create them)
- Are these translations "some random name in german" and "some random name in spanish" respectively? (otherwise change them)

But of course, the structure can be more complex. That's why I would be thankful for every library or app (or idea) that makes my life a bit easier.

Comment: Why you don't ask external source for json and do sync by yourself especially if this data is very unique?

Comment: @ŁukaszStaniszewski JSON would not be the problem but I would prefer to have a general solution without the need to sync every table manually. I could do that, sure, but it's a lot of work and requires more effort to react to changes in the models or to implement additional table synchronizations.